# XGBoost Inheritance: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn, data-science, xgboost

I'm refactoring some XGBoost functionality to minimize repeated code in my data science project. I have a common set of preprocessing steps I run in the beginning of any model build, and wanted to make a parent class, `Model`, that gets my data ready for the algorithm.

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

class Model:
    def __init__(self, dataframe, features, target, encoder):
        self.source = dataframe

        self.subset = self.source [self.source[target].notna()]

        self.X = self.subset[features]
        self.y = self.subset[target]

        self.categorical_features = list(self.X.select_dtypes(include = 'object').columns)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.preprocessor = make_column_transformer((self.encoder, self.categorical_features), remainder = 'passthrough')
        self.preprocessor.fit (self.source[features])

        self.X = self.preprocessor.transform (self.X)

        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split (self.X, self.y, test_size = 0.2)

class Model_XGB(Model):
    def fit(self, verbose = False):
        self.dtrain = xgb.DMatrix (self.X_train, labels = self.y_train)
        self.dtest = xgb.DMatrix (self.X_test, labels = self.y_test)

        params = {'max_depth': 2, 'eta': 1, 'objective': 'reg:squarederror', 'eval_metric': 'mae'}
        evallist = [(self.dtrain, 'train'), (self.dtest, 'eval')]
        num_round = 300
        self.booster = xgb.train (param, self.dtrain, num_round, evallist, early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose_eval = verbose)

model_xgb = Model_XGB(data, best_features, 'area', OrdinalEncoder())
model_xgb.fit (verbose = True)
```

My issue is, when I create a child class called `Model_XGB`, and attempt to add a new method `fit`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-e24c05d6f4dc> in <module>
     34 
     35 model_xgb = Model_XGB(data, best_features, 'area', OrdinalEncoder())
---> 36 model_xgb.fit (verbose = True)
     37 model_xgb.predict (data[best_features])

<ipython-input-71-e24c05d6f4dc> in fit(self, verbose)
     19 class Model_XGB(Model):
     20     def fit(self, verbose = False):
---> 21         self.dtrain = xgb.DMatrix (self.X_train, labels = self.y_train)
     22         self.dtest = xgb.DMatrix (self.X_test, labels = self.y_test)
     23 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

When did I pass `labels` to `__init__()`? `labels` is a method argument of `xgb`. Is there something about inheritance in python that I am misunderstanding, or is this related to these packages?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the argument name is `label` not `labels`! I thought the `__init__()` was referring to the object not the `DMatrix`!